# Django prefetched attribute returns null value

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

The requirement is to have subtopics prefetched at the Campaigns queryset as the attribute

```
prefetched_subtopics
```

but it currently returns ***null***

Models

```
class SubTopic(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class CampaignSubTopicAssn(HistoryMixin, Base):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign,
                                 related_name='subtopic_assn',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtopic = models.ForeignKey(SubTopic,
                                            related_name='campaign_assn',
                                            on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

View

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CampaignViewSet, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related(Prefetch('subtopic_assn', queryset=CampaignSubTopicAssn.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('subtopic', queryset=SubTopic.objects.all(), to_attr='prefetched_subtopics'))))
```

Comment: Use `.prefetched_subtopics.all()`.

Comment: you meant like this

`def subtopics(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'prefetched_subtopics'):
            return self.prefetched_subtopics.all()`
but still getting null and the hasattr(self, 'prefetched_subtopics') condition also fails.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem also tried this
`return super(CampaignViewSet, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related(Prefetch('subtopic_assn__subtopic', queryset=SubTopic.objects.all(), to_attr='prefetched_subtopics'))`

why does it also return null?